# Windows server 2016 unable to complete update KB4103723 (roll back on 99%)

Tags: windows-server-2016

i'm on a strange problem for the last 12 hours
unable to update the KB4103723, it rolls back every time.
I have tried all of these:

sfc /scannow: finish 100% but with error for windows protection error. i have looked at the CBS file and the only error is for the IIS MANAGER.LNK file that is corrupted: the path it says is c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\ **administrative tools** \iis manager.lnk

in my server the path is changed where **administrative tools** is actually **windows administrative tools**

i couldn't find any solution for that
so i thought maybe i will change all registry to the right path and restart my server (it is a cloned VM so i can play with that)

i did several changes but then got to 
Computer\HLM\SOFTWARE'MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\SHELLCOMPATIBILITY\INBOXAPP

if i try to change something there i get this error message: Cannot edit F2F852BA90DD4456_IIS_MANAGER_LNK_AMD64.LNK: ERROR WRITING THE VALUE'S NEW CONTENTS

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue that applies to: Windows 10 Version 1607 and Windows Server 2016. And as per this [May 8, 2018—KB4103723](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4103723) (OS Build 14393.2248) release:

> This update isn't available with express installation files for Windows Server 2016.

If you installed earlier updates, only the new fixes in this package will be downloaded and installed on your device.

You can also try [changing Windows update settings,](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2016/10/25/__trashed/) maybe a manual update

Comment: I was able to install it on 6 other VM from the same server 2016 ISO that i have. i don't understand you answer than